# Calendar hides when I change between months

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I have the following ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCal" runat="server" Text="V" 
    OnClientClick="javascript:document.getElementById('Cal').style.display='';return false;" />

<asp:Calendar ID="Cal" runat="server" style="display:none" 
    OnSelectionChanged="Cal_SelectionChangedInicio"></asp:Calendar>
```

When `btnCal` is pressed, the calendar is shown, and when a date is selected, it shows the date on a label, as seen below in the C# side:

```
protected void Cal_SelectionChangedInicio(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtCalI.Text = Cal.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();

    Cal.Style.Add("display", "none");
}
```

However, when I use the month change button in the calendar, the calendar hides itself and I have to click on the `btnCal` button to show it again.

Why is the calendar hiding when I use the select month button? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does the calendar hide as soon as you select a date as well?

Comment: My guess is that you are calling `Cal_SelectionChangedInici` as soon as any part of the selection changes. This means it will be called if the date part changes, or if the month part changes. You may want to remove the `OnSelectionChange` and add a submit button that will that will only set the label to the date once you are finished selecting all the wanted fields and press the button.